# Imagens não são exibidas, mesmo com path correto

Tags: html, css, imagem

não estou conseguindo fazer nenhum navegador exibir as imagens do grid, não é problema de caminho pois abri o código em outros editores que tem a opção de exibir o link da figura e abri-la em janela separada, também abri no Dreamweaver onde inclusive as imagens fica visíveis. Já testei algumas soluções encontradas em fóruns mas nada adiantou, então se alguém se dispuser a ajudar fico agradecido.
Segue o código:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Hotel Paraiso</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Projeto.css"/>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>
   <header>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Hotel Paraiso"></a>
      <nav>
         <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Reserva</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
      </nav>
   </header>

   <section class="hero">
      <h1>Conheça este paraíso chamado itacaré</h1>
      <h3>"Aconchego,conforto, simpatia e alto astral"</h3>
      <a class="btn" href="">Saiba mais</a>
   </section>

   <section class="conheca-o-hotel">
      <h3>Conheça o Hotel Paraiso!</h3>
      <p>Feche os olhos e imagine o paraíso. Um lugar no meio da mata Atlântica e banhado pelo mar, onde voce encontra paz, tranquilidade, conforto e comodidade.</p>
      <hr>
      <ul class="grid">
         <li class="small" style="background-image: url('img/itacare-01.jpg')"></li>
         <li class="large" style="background-image: url('img/itacare-02.jpg')"></li>
         <li class="large" style="background-image: url('img/itacare-03.jpg')"></li>
         <li class="small" style="background-image: url('img/itacare-04.jpg')"></li>
      </ul>
   </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Obs.: meu arquivo .css está na raiz, já as imagens na pasta img.
**CSS:**

```
/* RESET */
*{margin:0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif}
nav, ul{list-style: none;}
a{text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;opacity: 0.9;}
a:hover{opacity: 1;}
/* HEADER */
header{ width: 100%;position: absolute; top: 0; left:0;
   display:flex;
   justify-content: space-between;     /* Criou um espaço entre o logo e o menu */
   align-items: center;                /* Alinhou verticalmente no cento */
   padding: 20px 50px;                 /* padding topo/base e laterais */
   background-color: #fff;
}
/* TAMANHO DA IMAGEM */
header img{
   width: 200px;}
header img{
   margin-top: 15px;}          /* imagem um pouco abaixo do topo */
/* MENU EM LINHA */
header nav{
   display:flex}
/* COR DOS LINKS */
header li a{
   color:#191c03;}
/* MARGEM DO MENU */
header li{
   margin:0 15px;}
/* ACESSANDO O LEFT DO LI */
header li:first-child{
   margin-left: 0;}
header li:last-child{
   margin-right: 0;}
/* QUEBRA TELA EM 700 E PUXA O MENU PARA BAIXO DO LOGO */
/* Quando a tela atinge 700px, muda a direção do alinhamento de ROW (padrão do display:flex) para COLUMN */
@media(max-width: 700px){
   header{flex-direction: column;}
   header img{margin-bottom: 15px;}
}
/* HERO IMAGEM DE FUNDO */
/* Unidade de media VH: viewport heigh = percentual da tela; */
.hero{
   background-image: url(img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
   min-height: 100vh;
   color:#fff;

   /* H1 e H3 abaixo */
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;          /* coloca os dois paragrofos e o botão dispostos na vertical */
   justify-content: center;         /* alinha essa bagaça toda...*/
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center;              /* alinha o texto... */
}
.hero h1{
   font-size: 3.2rem;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.hero h3{
   font-size: 2rem;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.hero .btn{
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.678);
   border-radius: 4px;
   color: #f191c03;
   padding: 20px 50px;
   text-transform:uppercase;
}
/* Quando a tela atinge 700px, muda o tamnho do H1 e H3 */
@media(max-width: 700px){
   .hero h1{font-size: 2.5rem;}
   .hero h3{font-size: 1.5rem;}
}

/* CONHEÇA O HOTEL */
.conheca-o-hotel{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 100px 50px;
}
.conheca-o-hotel h3{
   font-size: 2rem;
   margin-bottom: 35px;
   /* text-align: center; */
   color: #191c03;
}
.conheca-o-hotel p{
   max-width: 800px;
   margin-bottom: 35px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #191c03;
}
.conheca-o-hotel hr{
   width: 200px;
   height: 2px;
   background-color: #191c03;
   margin-bottom: 70px;
   border: none;
}
. .conheca-o-hotel .grid{
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   /* quebra de linha */
}
.conheca-o-hotel .grid li{
    height: 350px;
    padding: 19px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-clip: content-box;    /* especifica se o fundo de um elemento, seja cor ou imagem, se extende debaixo de sua borda. */
    background-size: cover;          /* Por que precisa??? */
    background-position: center;     /* Centralizado dentro do LI. */
}
.conheca-o-hotel .grid li.small{
   flex-basis: 40%;                 /* Define o tamanho inicial (largura ou altura) que um Flex Item deve ter antes que o espaço ao seu redor seja distribuído por outras propriedades */
}.conheca-o-hotel .grid li.large{
   flex-basis: 60%;                 /* Define o tamanho inicial (largura ou altura) que um Flex Item deve ter antes que o espaço ao seu redor seja distribuído por outras propriedades */
}
```

Comment: Se vc olhar no console do navegador poderá ver uma mensagem dizendo que as imagens não foram encontradas (erro 404). Veja se mostra isso.

Comment: Não Sam, não tem nenhuma mensagem. Inclusive, dentro do console, na codificação css, se eu deixar a seta do mouse sobre o nome do arquivo, é exibido o caminho do arquivo. Mistério isso, to muito curioso...

Comment: Já testou em outro navegador? Testei aqui seu código e mostrou a imagem normalmente.

Comment: Sam, testei no Chrome, no Iron e no Edge, também testei em outro notebook, com windows 7, mesmo problema. Desabilitei o AdBlock Plus e nada...

Answer (score 1):

A sua classe .conheca-o-hotel .grid no CSS está com um ponto a mais 
Aqui -> . .conheca-o-hotel .grid

O erro 404 nas imagens ocorre caso não tenha as imagens no diretório especificado.

[image: Print do código destacando o erro]

Comment: Cara, sabe aquela vontade de se "auto-esbofetear"? Pois é... Essa vergonha deixou a lição de que devo caprichar mais ainda na limpeza do código e na atenção. Valeu amigo, um forte abraço, quem sabe um dia possa lhe recompensar.

Comment: Favor não [inserir código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/75104)